# Abrir Vários Programas de uma vez o CMD

Tags: cmd, prompt, ms-dos

Quero usar o CMD para abrir um programa várias vezes.

Exemplo quero abrir 5 vezes com um só comando.

E não como está nesse exemplo.

Então eu não quero desta forma e sim de alguma que abra com um só comando.

```
timeout 5
start chrome.exe
timeout 2
start chrome.exe
timeout 2
start chrome.exe
timeout 2
start chrome.exe
timeout 2
start chrome.exe
timeout 5
```

Answer (score 2):

1° Abra o CMD.

2° Digite:

```
FOR /L %V IN (1 1 5) DO start chrome %V
```

Ele vai abrir 5 paginas no Chrome.

Comment: Obg. =) Ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Digite o comando no arquivo batch:

```
start notepad.exe && calc.exe && mspaint.exe
```

Basta separar cada nome de processo por um "&&".

Comment: Obrigado, uma forma bem legal.

Answer (score 0):

Existem opções:

**1.** Executar o program em segundo plano (background): `Start /b`
**2.** Abrir o Chrome em janelas, em abas em ou ambos não em modo privado/ incócgnito:

- `start "" /b chrome --new-window`

```
for %%i in (pt.stackoverflow,stackoverflow,superuser,windows,google)do start "" /b chrome --new-window %%~i.com & timeout 5
```

- `start "" /b chrome --new-tab`

```
for %%i in (pt.stackoverflow,stackoverflow,superuser,windows,google)do start "" /b chrome --new-tab %%~i.com & timeout 5
```

- `start "" /b chrome --incognito`

```
for %i in (pt.stackoverflow,stackoverflow,superuser,windows,google)do start "" /b chrome --incognito %~i.com & timeout 5
```

- `start "" /b chrome --new-window --incognito`

```
for %%i in (pt.stackoverflow,stackoverflow,superuser,windows,google)do start "" /b chrome --new-window %%~i.com & timeout 5
```

- `start "" /b chrome --new-tab --incognito`

```
for %i in (pt.stackoverflow,stackoverflow,superuser,windows,google)do start "" /b chrome --new-tab --incognito %~i.com & timeout 5
```